# How to put training I've been doing during the COVID 19 outbreak on my resume?

Tags: resume, training, entrepreneurship

A few weeks into COVID-19 stumbled upon an entrepreneurial classes. In doing so I've learned how to do websites, web hosting, and internet marketing. Mind you this is only "training." The people designing the course explicitly state that they expect those taking the class to do the work... which I'm now getting around to doing.

But this training should (over time, as I understand more by doing) should make me a more valuable employee.

But here's the kicker... it's not an official "school" per se, yet (at least to me) the training is invaluable, as I've been wanting to do these things, but have had neither the time nor the finance to do so.

Comment: It's 2 things really. LinkedIn Learning paths AND a paid mentoring program combined. There are assignments, things to read, etc. And support for when I don't know how to do what they're instructing

Comment: Also, remember that the purpose of a resume is to get an interview.  Anything that gets attention, adds to that possibility.

Comment: @JesseCohoon (A) as has been said a million times on this site, unfortunately it is quite simply of very little value. {Indeed this is a million-times dupe question on here!}  But (B) sure it is totally harmless, no problem, to have this 5-word line item on your resume. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I graduated in December, a fresh CS graduate looking for a development position. I had a lot of on-the-side type skills like this that were meaningful to me and to my development, but weren't necessarily a university or an accredited course.

Consider adding an 'Independent Experience' section to your résumé. For me I included semi-related skills that were impressive, but not necessarily IT related. A website I had built for home automation, a database I manage for a small company, and some trivial Python programs I had written. Additionally, I even included hobbies like rebuilding cars, and included an achievement I've reached with this in the last year.

This section was easily the most talked about in each of my interviews. Employers want to hear the professional qualifications you possess, but showing that you have drive and wherewithal outside of work to build and see your own projects to the finish is very attractive. Most wanted to see the website, even if it wasn't for a front end position. You can easily bend these into talking points, building cars is a bit like development, it takes attention to detail, critical thinking and a whole lot of resilience. They love seeing the human side of you, and how you apply your everyday skills to how you function at work. Include it.

Answer (score 3):

Put the name of the organization that trained you under education, and what you studied, like this (apologies for formatting)

> **The NARF group............................................-2020

> .....Advanced widget formation

Comment: does this work for organizations that are not recognized / official  school? It literally is a paid *mentoring program*

Comment: @JesseCohoon it doesn't hurt, and if they ask you about it on the interview, you've got an opportunity to talk about it.  I know that a mentoring program would get my interest

Comment: @JesseCohoon - you are wildly overthinking it - YES mention it as briefly as possible on your resume.  It's just a line item "Completed pro Learning Path program under Janet Blackwater of IBM."  Nothing more to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not an accredited program with recognised certification it has limited value. Possibly if it had some positive result you could show in some way it might be more useful. Otherwise it's basically just something you did to pass the time.

[image]

Comment: accredited or not, in the coming weeks when employers ask for a website, I can present a professionally done website that is set up for affiliate marketing, and (possibly) ecommerce, and tied into my social media presence. Even at a different sector of the economy, it should be impressive that I took the time, energy, and cost out of pocket to do so

Comment: Yes, that is certainly worth something, so long as it's not Wordpress or similar.

Comment: It is WordPress, but I also know raw HTML, if i have to edit something specifically, and I don't mind messing with the back end database. There are quite a few companies out there who ask specifically for experience in that format, Google adwords (which 'm going to be using), as well as marketing directly through social media, which I'll also be taking advantage of..  .

Comment: @JesseCohoon good luck, it's not worth much, but better than nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If it were me, I wouldn't put any of it on my resume unless I earned some type of degree or certification.

How does this make you a more valuable employee or job candidate? Have you learned demonstrable real world skills from these training and mentoring programs that you can put to use for the immediate benefit of your current or future employer?

Is the mentoring program from a recognized program or institution? Does the mentoring program carry any weight or influence in your industry? Does the training program carry any weight or influence in your industry? Do either of them carry any weight or influence in general?

At the end of the day, how does this training and mentoring put you in a position of being noticed above the tens of millions of other people doing the very same thing? Will this training and mentoring bring any real and immediate value to your current or future employer?

I'm not trying to discourage you from pursuing further education and skills, and this is not a knock on you. I applaud your commitment to furthering yourself. I'm just saying that LinkedIn Learning courses and paid mentoring programs wouldn't carry much weight with me, and so I personally wouldn't put them on my resume.

Comment: Yes! In time it will be demonstrable. Maybe not immediately, but within literally a month or so I'll have an "end product" I can show potential employers. And quite possibly I'll be able to earn some $ from it. Though I'm not going to count on it replacing my income... yet! . .

Comment: ANYTHING that can help your chances of getting an interview should be on your resume

Comment: My point is that it probably isn't helpful, and only adds unneeded clutter. How valuable in the hiring process is a LinkedIn learning course in reality? How much weight does a LinkedIn learning course carry in making a hiring decision? My guess? None.